# Symbolic limit calculation, numeric value desired

Tags: matlab, math, symbolic-math

I am trying to calculate a limit operation of a function inside. Here is what I did:

```
x = 0;
f = (cos(x)*cos(h/2)*sin(h/2))/(h/2) - (sin(x)*sin(h/2)*sin(h/2))/(h/2);
limit(f,h,0)
ans =
1

limit(f,h,1)
ans =
2*cos(1/2)*sin(1/2)
```

I want to see what the numeric value of `2*cos(1/2)*sin(1/2)` is. How do I obtain this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `double` to evaluate the final expression:

```
double(limit(f,h,1))
ans =
    0.8415
```

[`limit`](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/limit.html) is a symbolic function, so it outputs symbolic functions. You can use `double` (or `single` or whatever numeric type you want) to convert to a number.